# UWP C# Lightning library GpioPin ValueChanged event MinnowBoard not working

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, gpio, windows-iot-core-10

I am using the new MinnowBoard Turbot Quad Core with Windows IoT Core 15063.

I created a UWP C# App with Visual Studio 2017 and added the "Microsoft.IoT.Lightning 1.1.0" library ([setup guide](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/lightningproviders), [GitHub](https://github.com/ms-iot/lightning), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IoT.Lightning)).

I want that the ValueChanged event is called, if the state of GpioPin changes. The following code is only working, if I use the default drivers and not the *Direct Memory Mapped Driver* with the Lightning library.

```cs
LowLevelDevicesController.DefaultProvider = LightningProvider.GetAggregateProvider();
var gpioController = GpioController.GetDefault();
var pin = gpioController.OpenPin(0);
pin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);
pin.ValueChanged += (gpioPin, args) =>
{
//Gets never called, if I use Lightning library and MinnowBoard Turbot Quad Core
};
```

Why the ValueChanged event of the GpioPin is not called when the state changes, if I use the MinnowBoard Turbot Quad Core with Windows IoT Core 15063, with the Lightning library?

Comment: Make sure you add the IOT and Desktop UWP SDK Extensions and low-level device capabilities based on [this doc](https://github.com/ms-iot/lightning).

Comment: Thanks, I added "Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP 15063", "Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP 15063", low-level device and the "109b86ad-f53d-4b76-aa5f-821e2ddf2141" capabilities to the project. But still not working.

Comment: I tested it and it works with Raspberry Pi 3 without any problems. So I guess that the Lightning library has a bug in combination with the MinnowBoard. Gets anyone the ValueChanged event to work with a MinnowBoard?

Comment: Issue fixed in GitHub repository https://github.com/ms-iot/lightning/pull/52. But not pushed in NuGet yet. I personally not tested it yet, but seems to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Sascha.